# Using multiple instances of wp_editor in Custom Post Type admin area

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, tinymce, wp-editor

I've written a custom plugin for my fishkeeping website which allows users to enter information about a species of tropical fish (i.e. "habitat", "distribution", "locality", etc).

Each of these are `meta` fields. They're currently drag/drop collapsible meta fields, using [cleditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) as the rich text editor of choice.

I opted for cleditor because back in WP 2.8 or whatever it was that I started the development of this plugin on, I couldn't work out a way of getting multiple instances of TinyMCE on to the same page.

By "multiple instances", I primarily mean editors with different `heights` and `buttons`.

Since then, I believe `wp_editor` command has come in to play, which might assist me somewhat.

**My question is this:** is it possible to have multiple, different instances of TinyMCE on the same page in the admin area of WP?

Here's my written version of a use case diagram!

- User clicks into "Species" menu, clicks "Add new species"
- User sees a number of meta boxes. I'm not too fussed if these are drag/droppable, but it'd be useful if they could be collapsed and if they could be removed from the screen entirely.
- Certain fields like "genus" and "species" are less than 25 characters each. Can TinyMCE be reduced to a single row? Not a huge problem if it can't.
- Certain fields will need a row of custom buttons - I know I can create these in TinyMCE, but can I have my `genus` field with 3 buttons on, my `habitat` field with the normal set of buttons on and my `water_chemistry` field with a row of 8 custom buttons?
- Certain fields will need to be different sizes - `genus` as I mentioned earlier will need to be as small as possible in both dimensions; `max_size_notes` will need to be 8 rows and `misc_notes` will need to be 16.
- I'd prefer to use `wp_editor()` if at all possible as it's clean and easy..!

A detailed, insightful answer would be hugely appreciated here. I've spent a great deal of time getting cleditor working and writing buttons for it, only to find that it has a number of formatting bugs :(

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think you mean [`wp_editor`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor)?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_editor

Comment: `the_editor` is Deprecated: 3.3 in favor of `wp_editor()`, try to use it instead, should be more stable, although it does have its own caveats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've got a lot of options.  some of which are:

to toot my own horn, i have used WP Alchemy to create repeating sortable tinyMCE editors with all the code available here

http://www.kathyisawesome.com/426/multiple-wordpress-wysiwyg-visual-editors/

there is also the http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ plugin. you can definitely have multiple instances, but you can't add dynamic blocks on the fly.