# Page with several user editable text content

Tags: customization, screen-layout

I'm new to WP (not to making websites) and I'm trying to see which is the ***community approved* standard way** of having a page with several user editable content (text, images…). I'm thinking on pages with custom layouts (e.g: `homepage`) where I have a 12 cols row, then 4-4-4 one, an image, etc. Note: the layout might follow a columns layout or not (it could be an user editable random divs mess).

Are `custom fields` (ACF) the way to go? Widgets? Maybe there is *the* plugin? I've seen some that let the user design the column layout as [Page Builder by SiteOrigin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/siteorigin-panels/). I'm not sure if it's too much power for the user.

Answer (score 0):

- [Create Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#capability_type) (CPT) with custom capabilities;
- [add User Role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) for these
  capabilities;
- assign this Role to the users you want to be able to administer that CPT;
- create multiple [metaboxes](http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-custom-meta-boxes-to-wordpress/) or [multiple editors](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114084/add-multiple-visual-editors-for-custom-post-type) (e.g. one per content block) for your CPT;
- create custom template for your CPT showing [metaboxes content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata);
- show that CPT as Front Page (See Justin Tadlock's [article](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/02/02/showing-custom-post-types-on-your-home-blog-page) how to do this).

Your users will be able to administer this CPT blocks only. And nothing else, if not stated differently. This way you don't give them too much power.

Can't say about Advanced Custom Fields or other plugins in conjunction with User Roles.

Comment: The question is not to show different CPTs but how to edit/manage different content areas in a page layout, e.g: front page with a hero image + some text, then three columns with three elements (title + paragraph + icon), then a large image (which can be user editable)… and so on. Being **all or parts of it user editable**.

Comment: I got it. My answer is updated.