# Multiple useres editing specified content

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, metabox, user-roles, capabilities

I work for a nonprofit with weekly courses for kids. Every week the course teachers update where and when next weeks course will be. We have about 10 courses every week.

So the teachers need to be able to update that information.

I did a bit of research an came up with something similar to what is described [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221854/page-with-several-user-editable-text-content) (Custom post type, add roles, ad metaboxes, make template,..)

This seems rather complex. We are migrating from Drupal 7, where I would have solved the problem similarly.

Is there any completely different (possibly wp-specific) approach to this problem?

Comment: You could always look at professional themes with these types of customizations if adding what you need feels too complex.

Comment: It's not that I dont't think I could pull it off, but considering I would need to install 3 Plugins just to make this work, I was wondering if there was a completely different approach. But I'll look into themes, thanks!

Comment: No need for multiple plugins if you're coding on your own: you can put it all in one.  Many of the professional themes will have what you're looking for built-in to the theme itself.